# Trimming common leading whitespace in an environment

Tags: code, white-space

I have an executable that performs semantic highlighting of files containing literate code.
It outputs a `.tex` file that I can source snippets from using catchfilebetweentags.

One issue I am facing is that indented code unsurprisingly ends up with leading whitespace. I would like to get rid of the *shared* prefix corresponding to the indentation while preserving the further leading whitespace that may exist in some line because in the source language indentation is meaningful.

Here is a typical example as a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%%% Code typesetting preamble

\newcommand{\CodeSpace}{\hphantom{ }}
\newcommand{\CodeNewLine}{\\}
\newcommand{\CodeKeyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\CodeIdentifier}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\newenvironment{code}
    {\vspace{1em}\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\obeyspaces\ttfamily}
    {\end{minipage}}

%%%

\begin{document}

\section{No leading whitespace}

\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{id}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}\CodeNewLine
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}
\end{code}

\section{Annoying leading whitespace}

\begin{code}
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{id}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}\CodeNewLine
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

It is rendered like so and, ideally, both sections should look the same:

[image]

I am happy to change the definition of the `code` environment, or of the
primitive `\CodeX` commands.

Comment: If you generate this tex code with an executable, you could change the method there. You could also use some existing [listing package](https://ctan.org/topic/listing), depending on your use case.

Comment: That would mean that the syntax highlighter would output something with a different layout than the source (that's already dubious), and that is not even a valid program (which IMO is a big issue). I want a separation of concerns: the highlighter highlights, the `code` environment typesets.

Comment: Should it be automatically detected what the shared prefix is, i.e. how many spaces should be removed. Or should this be passed, e.g. as a parameter from the `code` environment. The former would require an extra compile pass and would be a bit more complicated. Are there only the four commands `\CodeSpace`, `\CodeNewLine`, `\CodeKeyword`, and `\CodeIdentifier` inside the `code` environment and no text that is not inside one of these commands?

Comment: There are more commands (e.g. `\CodeComment`, `\CodeFunction`, `\CodeData`, etc.) but the indentation level is determined by the indentation of the first line so it should hopefully be possible to make a decision by looking only at the first bunch of *contiguous* `\CodeSpace` and ignoring everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- added Booleans `firstlinestart` and `linestart` (using `\newtoggle` of package `etoolbox`)
- added counters `currentcodespaces` and `codespaces`
- extended `\CodeSpace`:

  - count spaces with counter `currentcodespaces`
  - ignore spaces if at the start of the firstline (`firstlinestart`) or if at the start of another line (`linestart`) and `currentcodespaces` <= `codespaces`
- defined a command `\CodeNoSpace` that should be called by each Code command except for `\CodeSpace`

  - toggles `linestart` and to false
  - sets counter `codespaces`, if it's the first line
- extended `\CodeNewLine`:

  - resets `currentcodespaces` to 0 and `linestart` to true
  - *optional for debugging:* show originally leading spaces (in red)
- `code` environment sets both toggles to true and counter `currentcodespaces` to 0

#### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%% Code typesetting preamble
\newtoggle{firstlinestart}
\newtoggle{linestart}
\newcounter{currentcodespaces}
\newcounter{codespaces}

\newcommand{\CodeNoSpace}{%
    % This command should be called by each Code command that is not \CodeSpace
    \togglefalse{linestart}%
    \iftoggle{firstlinestart}{%
        \togglefalse{firstlinestart}%
        \setcounter{codespaces}{\thecurrentcodespaces}%
    }{}%
}

\newcommand{\CodeSpace}{%
    \stepcounter{currentcodespaces}%
    \ifboolexpe{
        togl{firstlinestart} or (
            togl{linestart} and test{ \ifnumless{ \value{currentcodespaces} }{ \value{codespaces} + 1 } } 
        )
    }{%
        % ignore spaces
    }{%
        \hphantom{ }%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\CodeNewLine}{%
    \CodeNoSpace%
    \quad\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize\textrm{(originally: \arabic{codespaces} leading spaces)}}% this line is just for debugging
    \\%
    \setcounter{currentcodespaces}{0}%
    \toggletrue{linestart}%
}

\newcommand{\CodeKeyword}[1]{\CodeNoSpace\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\CodeIdentifier}[1]{\CodeNoSpace\textit{#1}}

\newenvironment{code}{%
    \vspace{1em}%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \obeyspaces%
    \ttfamily%
    \setcounter{currentcodespaces}{0}
    \toggletrue{firstlinestart}
    \toggletrue{linestart}
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
}

%%%

\begin{document}

\section{No leading whitespace}

\begin{code}
\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{id}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}\CodeNewLine
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}
\end{code}

\section{No annoying leading whitespace anymore}

\begin{code}
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{id}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}\CodeNewLine
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}
\end{code}

\begin{code}
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{let}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{id}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}\CodeNewLine
\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeSpace\CodeKeyword{=}\CodeSpace\CodeIdentifier{xs}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Btw this looks great, I just have had a hectic few days and have not had the time to try to integrate your solution into my larger project. I'll hopefully get it done this coming week and come back to accept the answer.

Comment: I eventually managed to come back to my project and your solution works beautifully!